# Lexmark 7170 printer keeps complaining about left cartridge incorrect.

Tags: inkjet-printer

Lexmark 7170 printer keeps complaining about left cartridge incorrect I was using a new 34 cartridge when this happened.  I changed to a new 32 cartridge and it keeps complaining.  Is my printer dead.  Should I look for another printer.   Computer is a Dell XPS running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this troubleshooting:
http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&productCode=LEXMARK_X7170&locale=EN&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_US&id=SO3494 ?

It is Lexmark's troubleshooting guide for the incorrect cartridge error you are receiving.

Comment: Hi!  Link-only answers are a no-no due to possible future link-rot.  Please paraphrase and include pertinent information in your answer.